# Gstreamer dynamic pipeline : Camera Preview on HDMI Camera Video Recording on File

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

hello I have a problem with Caps, when i try to use this pipeline :gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! caps ! nvvidconv ! caps ! tee !  queue1 ! nvvideosink
I get `:WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "caps"`

thanks

Answer (score 0):

GstElement and GstCaps are two different things.

Caps is like a structure that can define the stream media type and some stream specifications. It is not a GstElement. Therefore, you should use capsfilter element which is a GstElement and then set your caps into it.

Your pipeline should be like this:

v4l2src ! capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=I420" ! nvvidconv  ! tee ! queue ! nvvideosink 
(Careful, your caps may need to be on GPU like 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM)'. I explained on below continue to read.


You can arrange your format whatever you want. If you are not sure your camera's format, just don't set it, like: caps="video/x-raw,width=640,height=480"

When you use Capsfilter, you force your pipeline to get THAT stream settings. For instance, if your camera does not support 640x480, your pipeline gives crash!
If you are not sure your camera's specifications, just use nvvidconv or videoconvert element which converts stream for you.

If you are not sure whatever you should do, try this pipeline:
v4l2src ! nvvidconv ! nvvideosink

Warning: nvvidconv and nvvideosink probably works on GPU. So if you try to use videoconvert with nvvideosink program might crash because videoconvert works on CPU and nvvideosink may not be able to work on CPU.

Give it a look to that
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/window-playback-using-nvvideosink/42346 , he built his pipeline to be able to work on GPU. He used nvcamerasrc for gettings stream from GPU. v4l2src gets only from CPU. 
You decide whether to get stream from CPU or GPU. Try to look at this link too for your pipeline creation:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gstreamer-input-nvcamerasrc-vs-v4l2src/50658/2